# In Android Studio, What is the best way to share JSON data between devices in a workplace

Tags: android-studio

I have made a team-work app in Android Studio. And i have difficult with what to use to share this data to other people that is in the workplace.
One device will be used for setting up and editing the team-work list, and then make it available for all the others to update on their devices.
I have looked att WIFI-Direct, Firebase and bluetooth. But i don't know if any of them is any good for this.
And all WIFI-direct demos from Google seem to be deleted on net.
Until now, i see the only solution to use a database on my own server, but i want it to only be locally in the workplace, and not on net.
Is it possible to make the other devices to receive the new updated team-work JSON data locally? And what is the best way to do it?
I add a picture of the app, for easier to understand.
[The team-work app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONid0.jpg)

Comment: I'm trying to implement Nodejs server inside the app. Seems to be the best way. The best way for easiest getting the update from the main device.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after some hours, and hope it will help others too.

With the help of these links:

https://code.janeasystems.com/nodejs-mobile/getting-started-android
https://github.com/JaneaSystems/nodejs-mobile-samples/tree/master/android

I have created an test Android app implementing nodejs.

When running this app it starts the nodejs server, and i can connect the other devices to this device and just download the updated JSON data.
Just like this:

192.168.0.102:3000/getupdate

It returns with a JSON string. And i convert it to a JSON object, and saving the JSON data to the internal storage, and refresh the team-work list. And the user has updated his device with the new data.
Just perfect.

Users don't have to set up connection every time. Only the ip address in their settings one time.

This was the best solution for my app. Easy and simple, but it took some days to figure out what to use.

Now i don't have to have a server on the internet for it to work.

Comment: I also tried Cordova to do this. I made it, but i deleted it again after i learned that Cordova always brakes apart after every new Android studio updates, And there is not much documentation and often it's too old, and the documentation is very bad, and not easy to understand.  So, i went back to using the normal Nodejs mobile in Android Studio. This makes it more stable and create less work.